# Dataframe count of positive values in range as a new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=list('XYZ'))
df.insert(0, 'NAME', pd.Series(list('ABCDEFGHIJ')))
```

[image]

and would like to have the count of positive entries in specified columns (`'X', 'Y', 'Z'`) as a new column to the dataframe.

[image]

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
df['COUNT'] = df.select_dtypes(include='float64').gt(0).sum(axis=1)
#  NAME         X         Y         Z  COUNT
# 0    A -0.033066 -1.064625 -0.299286      0
# 1    B  0.902976 -1.703256 -0.011417      1
# 2    C -2.537364 -0.216643  1.051398      1
# 3    D  1.073677 -1.486599 -0.827829      1
# 4    E  2.157901  0.425371 -1.659263      2
# 5    F -1.589662 -0.382535  0.454324      1
# 6    G  0.487965  0.279265  0.820486      3
# 7    H  0.496104 -0.680161  0.763793      2
# 8    I -0.034518 -0.479307 -0.071954      0
# 9    J -0.170412  0.558505 -1.742784      1
```

The `select_dtypes` method is pretty self-explanatory, but it's useful in cases like this for filtering to columns of a certain dtype without needing to worry about column names.

The `.gt` method ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.gt.html)) tests Series values for being greater than the argument value (in this case `0`), and returns boolean values. We can then calculate the row-wise sum of True values to get the count of values meeting our criterion.

Comment: Clever way of doing it. I think this answer could be really well recieved if you add the [`gt documentation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.gt.html) and explain it more! this is another one of those "hidden features" in pandas

Comment: Thanks @MattR, and I agree, I've revised the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution, so I'm posting here for future reference.

```
np.random.seed(11)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=list('XYZ'))
df.insert(0, 'NAME', pd.Series(list('ABCDEFGHIJ')))

cols = df.columns.difference(['NAME'])
df['COUNT'] = df[df[cols] > 0].count(axis=1)
```

[image]